# How do I stick a body to the ground in Box2D?

Tags: javascript, box2d

I want to create a body like `b2CircleShape` or `b2PolygonShape` for e.x. and use a joint to connect/stick it to the "**ground**" (screen?/world?), so that when I drag it with the mouse and release it, it gets dragged back to its original location by virtue of the joint.

Do I just create two bodies, one that is fixed in place and another that can move and create a joint between them?

Or do I connect the body to some kind of a "**ground**"?

So far I got this: http://jsfiddle.net/AP2D6/5/

I'm using **Box2DWeb**: http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mouse joint or a motor joint to do this. The motor joint is a relatively new addition to Box2D so most likely is not in Box2DWeb yet.

To do it with a mouse joint, just do everything as you normally would for a 'real' mouse joint (ie. one that the player is actually controlling) except the target point does not move. You will need to set the maximum force for the 'sticking to ground' mouse joint to a weaker value than the one used to drag the body around, otherwise you wont be able to move it :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for "gravity"?

i've used the java port but:

when creating the World instance, the second argument is the Vector2d rapresenting the direction and force of the gravity. This gravity is applied every step to all not-static bodyes

if you want "custom gravity" that is different for body, then create a Vector2d that rapresent the direction and force of the body's gravity, then every loop just do apply it to the body

```
customGravity = new b2Vec2(x,y)
body.applyForce(customGravity)
[...]
world.step()
```